# requires api 11, 14, My app using min is api 9 but runs on api 9

Tags: android

is there a way to use something else to replace the import android.provider.CalendarContract. * ?

// here CalendarContract only support API 14.

```
    Uri.Builder builder = null;
        builder = android.provider.CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, start);
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, end);
    return builder.build();
```

Comment: what is the question man??

Comment: that's bad... or good? can't understand. And what is a question? And what is the problem with the code? And what should it do?

Comment: I using a app calendar like google calendar. But when I use CalendarContract that CalendarContract error. API 9 not running. CalendarContract only support API 14.